# Varios datos en una sola celda (Grilla) GeneXus 15 para WEB

Tags: genexus

Buen día para todos, tengo una grilla hecha en GeneXus 15 con JAVA.
[image: Grilla]

Las tablas involucradas son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La Grilla(Tabla) la estoy llenando con la tabla "contactoempresa(Tabla base de la grilla) pero los correos están en la tabla canalcontacto y quisiera poder mostrarlos en la grilla.

También adjunto mi grilla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es que mi grilla quede así o algo parecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la atención
Estaré a la espera de sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y ayudanos con las 2 transacciones que intervienen en la grilla que deseas armar, su estructura y la realción que tienen. Por que como lo veo basta que con un for y punto de control hacia la otra transacción. Saludos.

Comment: Disculpen el no haberme explicado bien, esta vez adjunte más imágenes para que se te entienda lo mejor posible.
Gracias Rostan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo ahora que nos has proporcionado la estructura lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

Tu tabla base es **contactoempresa**

```
For Each
    Order idContacto
    &emails = NullValue(&emails)  //  Se basea la variable que concatenará los correos
    For Each  //  Join hacia la tabla canalcontacto
        Order idContacto
        &emails += contactoemail + NewLine()
    EndFor

    Load  //  Load del Grid
EndFor
```

Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

- Partes de la tabla base para obtener los datos del contacto.
- Haces un Join hacia la tabla de canalcontacto, en la cual se cargará la variable &email con los correos seguida de un **NewLine()** para el salto de línea.
- Load de la Grilla

Esto lo debes hacer en el evento **Load**, en caso de tener una sola grilla en el web form, basta con:

```
Event Load
    //  Tu codigo
EndEvent
```

En caso de tener varias grillas:

```
Event TuGrid.load
    //  Tu codigo
EndEvent
```

Y al final, para que los emails te salgan verticalmente, en la propiedades de la variable &email (en el web form) deberás ponerle Autoresize: **True**.

Espero te sirva mi ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Genial, eres un crack ¡¡¡
Funcionó como lo esperaba, muchas gracias por el apoyo.
Espero no abusar, pero quisiera realizarte otra consulta.
si no es mucha molestia.

Comment: Haha, gracias. No olvides dar por resuelta tu pregunta con esta respuesta. Y claro no hay problema, formula una nueva pregunta en el foro, a lo mejor alguien mas puede aportar tambien. Saludos.